# Why is asyncio aiohttp taking so much time to load only 40 urls in the code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In the sample code below, I am trying to load 40+ urls with asyncio aiohttp
For some reason, it takes a lot of time to load them. I have seen examples everywhere on dev.to, stackoverflow etc where it loads a 100 urls in less than 3 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os
import time
async def fetch_url(url, save_to_file=False):
    try:
        print('loading...', url)
        timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=30)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout, trust_env=True) as session:
            async with session.get(url, raise_for_status=True, ssl=False) as response:
                text = await response.text('utf-8')
                print('success...', url)
                if save_to_file:
                    current_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S') 
                    name_part = urlparse(url).netloc
                    file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'extras', 'feeds', current_timestamp, name_part)
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_name), exist_ok=True)
                    with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
                        f.write(text)
                return (url, response.status, len(text))
    except Exception as e:
        print('failure...', url)
        return (url, -1)

async def main(urls, save_to_file):
    tasks=[fetch_url(url, save_to_file=save_to_file) for url in urls]
    results=await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    return results

urls=['https://bitcoinmagazine.com/feed', 'https://coingape.com/feed/', 'https://cryptocomes.com/rss_feed', 'https://www.ccn.com/crypto/feed', 'https://bitcoinist.com/feed/', 'https://bitcoinexchangeguide.com/feed/', 'https://ethereumworldnews.com/feed/', 'https://cryptoslate.com/feed/', 'https://coinspeaker.com/feed/', 'https://cryptovest.com/feed/', 'https://blockonomi.com/feed/', 'https://cryptobriefing.com/feed/', 'https://crypto-news.net/feed/', 'https://www.newsbtc.com/feed/', 'https://financemagnates.com/cryptocurrency/feed/', 'https://bitcoinchaser.com/feed/', 'https://coinjournal.net/feed/', 'https://zycrypto.com/feed/', 'https://coindoo.com/feed/', 'https://cryptocurrencynews.com/feed/', 'https://unhashed.com/feed/', 'https://insidebitcoins.com/feed', 'https://coinpedia.org/feed/', 'https://bitrazzi.com/feed/', 'http://cryptopost.com/feed/', 'https://bitpinas.com/feed/', 'https://cryptoverze.com/feed/', 'https://eng.ambcrypto.com/feed/', 'https://beincrypto.com/feed/', 'https://bitcoinnews.com/feed/', 'https://blockspoint.com/feed.rss', 'https://blokt.com/feed', 'https://btcwires.com/feed/', 'https://chepicap.com/en/rss', 'https://coinfomania.com/feed/', 'https://coinnounce.com/feed/', 'https://cryptoblockwire.com/feed/', 'https://cryptodisrupt.com/feed/', 'https://cryptopolitan.com/feed/', 'https://www.cryptovibes.com/feed/', 'https://dashnews.org/feed/', 'https://livebitcoinnews.com/feed/', 'https://decrypt.co/feed', 'https://www.theblockcrypto.com/rss.xml', 'https://www.cryptoglobe.com/latest/feed/', 'https://dailyhodl.com/feed/', 'https://cryptoiq.co/feed/', 'https://cryptopotato.com/feed/', 'https://www.coininsider.com/feed/', 'https://www.trustnodes.com/feed', 'https://btcmanager.com/feed/', 'https://cointelegraph.com/rss', 'https://www.coindesk.com/arc/outboundfeeds/rss/?outputType=xml', 'https://news.bitcoin.com/feed/', 'https://cryptoninjas.net/feed/']
start = time.perf_counter()
asyncio.run(main(urls, save_to_file=False))
print('elapsed time %s', time.perf_counter() - start)
```

**Update**

I am on python 3.9.7 on Apple M1 and it takes me 30-60 seconds to run this

Comment: python version 3.9.7, aiohttp latest version

Comment: maybe the remotes are just slow?  But you are also doing file system access, which will slow things down a bit.  EDIT: just seen the `False`

Comment: Loading all those urls taks 4.8s for me, which I certainly wouldn't call slow.  I think you're just running into genuine slow down (network, load, etc) rather than any problem in the code

Comment: 2e0by0 takes 30-60 seconds for me,  I am on Apple M1 mac mini

Comment: ...but probably on a slower internet/wifi connection than me.  Incidentally that's amusing, as I thought I had the slowest internet in the western world.  If you really don't think that's the issue, profile and see where the time is being spent.

Comment: Note that this will run for as long as it takes to download the _slowest_ of the URLs. Here is a simple idea: add a line with `print(url)` just before the `return` statement in `fetch_url`. That way you will know exactly which site or sites cause the slowdown.